# Remove column customer grid with observer

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer, adminhtml, grid

I'm trying to remove some columns from customer grid, but is not working, I've tried several similar events, but none of them work.

my config.xml

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
            <observers>
                <manage_adminhtml>
                    <class>manage_adminhtml/observer</class>
                    <method>getCustomerGrid</method>
                </manage_adminhtml>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

and my observer

```
class Manage_Adminhtml_Model_Observer
{
    public function getCustomerGrid( $observer )
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

        if ($block->getId() == 'customerGrid') {

            $block->removeColumn('group');
            $block->removeColumn('email');

            $block->sortColumnsByOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do can be achieved with [GridControl](https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl).

We use the event `adminhtml_block_html_before` and then call `$params->getBlock()->removeColumn($params->getColumn()->getName());`